# Compose with Hilt last version (2.35) problem: Unable to find method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use Compose and Hilt (lastest version) on Android Canary, but i couldn't sync the project. Error message below:

```
Unable to find method ''void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension, com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)''
'void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension, com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
```

My build.gradle

```
ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
        def hilt_version = "2.35"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
```

My build.gradle(:app)

```
    //Dagger - Hilt
    def hilt_version = "2.35"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: this solution work fine [stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating to hilt version `2.36` seems to have resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's some error with new version of Hilt, temporary fix for this is to add this maven part to top level gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url  "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        content {
            includeModule("com.google.dagger", "hilt-android-gradle-plugin")
        }
    }
}
```

Then Hilt class path look like this:

```
classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:HEAD-SNAPSHOT")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta05 and hilt version 2.37
github link
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2700#issuecomment-873259257